# VS Browser-Link & Self-Hosted Web Application

Tags: owin, self-hosting, katana, browser-link

Is it possible to use VS Browser-Link together with a self-hosted web application?

I know that the Browser-Link uses SignalR. How can I add the Browser-Link feature to my web server?

Web app framework: Katana Self-Hosted

Any hints or ideas?